# playframework2.6 on azure

Tags: azure, playframework

playframework2.6をazure上で使用したいのですが、利用可能でしょうか？
eclipseのazureツールキットを使って、playアプリケーションをデプロイしたいのですが、
デプロイしようとしても、デプロイボタンがアクティブになりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/171339

Comment: 利用しているのはazureのWebAppServiceです。